# how to rotate 3d perspective camera for isometric tiled map in andenigne

Tags: android, andengine

i am working on isometric tiled map game.here in introduction i want to show complete game field .so i used

```
this.mCamera = new ZoomCamera(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT) {
    @Override
    public void onApplySceneBackgroundMatrix(final GLState pGLState) {
        final float widthRaw = this.getWidthRaw();
        final float heightRaw = this.getHeightRaw();

        pGLState.orthoProjectionGLMatrixf(0, widthRaw, heightRaw, 0, getZNear(), getZFar());
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
        if (timeCounter >= 1) {
            mCamera.setRotation(i);
            timeCounter = 0;
            i=i+1;
        }
        timeCounter += pSecondsElapsed;
        super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
    }
};
```

but its rotating 2d view .i want to rotate in  3d perspective .how can i rotate camera in 3d perspective  in andenigne GLES2.0.
please suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rotate your camera in 3D. The appearance of 3D is caused by the fact that the artwork is drawn in perspective. Rotating the artwork does not cause the artwork to change the way its drawn any more than rotating a piece of paper with a drawing on it would cause a 3D transformation. To rotate in 3D you need to be using a 3D engine.

Comment: thak you.for your suggestion http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WE849SPLkc8 i want to develop a game as simillar in you tube.which engine is best to work on it.please suggest me.

Comment: @user2126175: you can do it in AndEngine. As *Plastic Sturgeon* said, the 3D effect of the game is based on the artwork. So just create your Sprites from a birds POV and they will look as 3D as in the youtube video. If you want you can use an isometric tile grid as in the game to enhance the 3D impression. Have a look at https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension.git. With this extention you can use "Tiled" as map editor.

Comment: @gamedroids - how would you achieve the rotation? Andengine does isometric, no problem, but how would you rotate the camera? I have not seen any game do this without a 3D engine, and I'd love to know how its done.

Answer (score 1):

Several times I stumbled upon [this tutorial](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/3d-perspective-tutorial-t1790.html) in the AndEngine Forum, where it states that it is possible to rotate the Camera in a way to show distant objects further away (smaller). It is made for the AndEngine GLES1 but it should be possible to adapt it to GLES2.

AndEngine knows a z-axis. The position on that axis is set automatically based on the order in which you attach the Sprites to the Scene. However, you should set it manually. In most cases it will be sufficient to set the z-axis according to the y-position (z-axis = y-axis) every time a Sprite changes its position.

```
public class YourSprite extends Sprite{
     ...
     @Override
     setPosition(float x, float y){
        super.setPosition(x,y);
        this.setZIndex(y);
     }
}
```

If you then manage to implement the camera rotation as described in the tutorial, together with the z-axis you should have a pretty realistic 3D effect.

However, I never tried that tutorial, because most games that use the Bird's-eye view (as the game from the youtube link you provided) don't need a real vanishing point, since the display is most likely so small, so the player wouldn't notice anyway. So I stick to changing the position on the z-axis. But I would certainly like to know more if anyone manages to rotate the camera!

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses exactly what the original poster asked, but I upvoted because I think its a legitimate approach to the problem. But to make a game with a rotating camera work, you would need more than that, as you would also need Z sorting and other 3D tricks to make it work. In short: you'd end up writing a 3D engine.

Comment: Oh, maybe I misunderstood the question then. I really thought we where talking about rotating the camera to *produce* the 3D effect in the first place and not rotating the camera on the y-axis in a 3D world – I mean that's for sure, in AndEngine we can choose the *Bird's-eye view* but we can't rotate the bird :) But thanks for the upvote!